# Elsa Workflow - It possible to re-execute a workflow from a specific custom activity?

Tags: c#, .net-core, elsa-workflows

I would need to integrate the functionality to backtrack and re-execute the workflow from a specific custom activity, according to you is it possible to do this ?
Where can I find references about this ?

Example of the desired functionality:

[Workflow viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njCwY.jpg)

[Workflow definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ya41w.jpg)

I haven't tried any avenues yet, I would like to be able to launch the workflow from a specific execution and a specific activity, running the context from that specific point.